# Оформление предложения.

Tags: пунктуация

"ЦТ, ВУЗы, поступление – только такие мысли посещали головы выпускников 2012 года первые месяцы лета".
Может, на месте тире нужен какой-то другой знак?

Comment: Интересное выражение "первые месяцы лета". Июнь-то точно первый, август - последний. А вот что с июлем делать? )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да нет, все верно. Тире стоит после однородных членов предложения перед обобщающим словом.

Answer (score 0):

"ЦТ, ВУЗы, поступление – только такие мысли посещали головы выпускников 2012 года первые месяцы лета."   Тире ставим после однородных членов перед обобщающим словом, если слово содержит общее лексическое значение для данного ряда однородных членов. Кроме того, обобщающее является тем же самым членом предложения, что и однородные. Здесь ЦТ, ВУЗы, поступление - это однородные подлежащие, мысли - это тоже подлежащее. Следовательно тире нужно ставить.
А по поводу "первые месяцы лета", я согласна, вариант интересный.